# what is >i2 data type Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some data file which is array of arrays...For example:

```
[[142 132 138 ..., 130 128 129]
[137 134 135 ..., 124 117 124]
[127 138 131 ..., 131 131 127]
..., 
[129 131 136 ..., 123 130 117]
[134 141 133 ..., 133 124 121]
[133 138 136 ..., 131 122   0]]
```

This file has 2.8 MiB and type `>i2`.. File is fits and I know that its type is `int16`, but what does `>i2` mean in Python?

How I can convert this data file to `float`?

So I have three data fits files, Dark frame, flat field and image. I need create correction of image. This data files I need convert to `float` and make some operation (divide and difference of data files values) a then convert result to origin data type `int`.

I created script which make corrections but I have problem that the result correction image has 6.3 MiB and don't has 2.8 MiB:

```
import numpy as np
import pyfits
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import glob


dark=glob.glob('.../ha/dark/*.fits')
flat=glob.glob('.../ha/flat/*.fits')
img=glob.glob('.../ha/*.fits')

sumd0 = pyfits.open(dark[0])
sumdd=sumd0[0].data
sumdd.astype(float)
for i in range(1,len(dark)):
     sumdi=pyfits.open(dark[i])
     sumdi=sumdi[0].data
     sumdd=sumdd.astype(float)+sumdi.astype(float)
dd=sumdd/len(dark)

sumf0 = pyfits.open(flat[0])
sumff=sumf0[0].data
sumff.astype(float)
for i in range(1,len(flat)):
     sumfi=pyfits.open(flat[i])
     sumfi=sumfi[0].data
     sumff=sumff.astype(float)+sumfi.astype(float)

ff=sumff/len(flat)

df=(ff-dd)

for n in range(len(img)):
    with pyfits.open(img[n],mode='update',memmap=True) as im:
        imgg=im[0].data
        header=im[0].header
        imgg.astype(float)
        imgg=(imgg-dd)/df
        imgg.astype(int)
plt.imshow(imgg,cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r,vmin=0.5,vmax=1.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> big_end_arr = np.ndarray(shape=(2,),dtype='>i2', buffer=big_end_str)
>>> big_end_arr[0]
1
>>> big_end_arr[1]
770
```

> Note the array dtype above of >i2. The > means ‘big-endian’ (< is little-endian) and i2 means ‘signed 2-byte integer’. For example, if our data represented a single unsigned 4-byte little-endian integer, the dtype string would be < u4 .

The  type specifiers  are listed in the [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#defining-structured-arrays) docs.

Comment: OK...but how I can get from my data type float ?

Comment: I thought just .astype(float) and I get convert array from i2 to float

Comment: Nothing...when I use data.astype(float) and then print data.dtype I get again origin type >i2

Comment: That is because you are not changing the original array, `print(data.astype(float) )` and you will see it returns a copy, try `data = data.astype(float, copy=False)`

Comment: I got error line 14, in <module>
    sumdd = sumdd.astype(float,copy=False)
TypeError: astype() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Och..I see..I have bad numpy version

Comment: OK now It is work...but how I get data from float to int? When I write data.astype(int,copy=False) and this data is in float I get float again

Comment: If you write `data = data.astype(int, copy=False)`,  the dtype will be int

Comment: Ok It is work now...but when I convert float data to int (origin data is >2i) I get other image... Is it any option how preserve data as float but result it will be in int due size? Or how I can convert float data to >2i type?